# Add infinite number of entity inside the same entity

Tags: ios, core-data, entity-relationship

How to add infinite number of entity inside the same entity in core data. For instance i tried [workflowy](https://workflowy.com/#) method of adding tasks(like infinite tree structure). But i struggled in creating the core data model structure. Also i searched regarding this but not able to get the preferred results for my keywords.
Give below picture is the DB structure sample i tried for adding same entity inside the parent entity.

[image]

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're asking. What do you mean about storing an "infinite number"? What do you mean by "entity inside the same entity"?

Comment: I think you only need a Task entity and a one-to-many relationship with itself. A task has one supertask and many subtasks.

Comment: @TomHarrington thank you for your reply. "entity inside the same entity" -> means adding parent entity to the same parent entity. For instance check the workflowy link given above, where you can add task inside parent task, I mean infinite number of tasks we can add to one single task in the form of tree structure.